# Conditional [required] attribute in Angular 9 form - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I have a radio button like so:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': saCitizen.invalid }">

        <label for="saCitizen">
            Do you have South African citizenship?:
        </label>

        <div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="saCitizen" id="saCitizen_yes" [value]="true" [(ngModel)]="registration.saCitizen" required #saCitizen="ngModel">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="saCitizen_yes">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="saCitizen" id="saCitizen_no" [value]="false" [(ngModel)]="registration.saCitizen" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="saCitizen_no">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
                            
        <div *ngIf="saCitizen.errors?.required" class="invalid-feedback">
            SA Citizen is required
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I then have a texbox asking for the ID number:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': idNumber.invalid }">

        <label for="idNumber">
            RSA ID Number:
        </label>

        <input id="idNumber" name="idNumber" class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="registration.idNumber" #idNumber="ngModel" maxlength="13" minlength="13" pattern="^\d{13}$" [required]="registration.saCitizen" />

        <div *ngIf="idNumber.errors?.required" class="invalid-feedback">
            RSA ID Number is required
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The key part is: `[required]="registration.saCitizen"` on the textbox. This gives rise to the following error when I change the radio button:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

How do I avoid this error but keep the conditional validation / required aspect?

Comment: can you post the code where you are updating registration.saCitizen value

Comment: @FatehMohamed that's bound to the first control - the radio button in the top code snippet.

Comment: @Sean `[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': saCitizen.invalid }"` this line has problem remove it and check error has gone or not.