# Changing validations of a select field dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, forms, validation, required, ng-class

I am encountering an issue with my Angular application where I'm dynamically changing the `required` attribute of a select field in a form after it has been submitted.

**evaluations.component.html**

```html
<form
  novalidate
  #form="ngForm"
  (ngSubmit)="form.form.valid && onSubmit()">
  <div *ngFor="let evaluation of evaluations; index as index">
    <select
      name="evaluator{{index}}"
      id="evaluator{{index}}"
      #evaluatorField="ngModel"
      [(ngModel)]="evaluatorId"
      [required]="isEvaluatorRequired"
      [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': form.submitted && evaluatorField.invalid}">
      <option *ngFor="let evaluator of evaluators" [ngValue]="evaluator._id">
        {{evaluator.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="operation" #operation="ngModel" id="operation-suggested" [value]="'APPROVE'"
      [(ngModel)]="operation" (ngModelChange)="onOperationChange($event)" required />
    <input type="radio" name="operation" #operation="ngModel" id="operation-decline" [value]="'DECLINE'"
      [(ngModel)]="operation" (ngModelChange)="onOperationChange($event)" required />
    ...
  </div>
  ...
  <button type="submit" id="save">
    Save
  </button>
</form>
```

`isEvaluatorRequired` changes on the call to `onOperationChange(...)` done when the operation value changes.

**evaluations.component.ts**

```js
...
onOperationChange(operation: OperationStatus) {
  this.isEvaluatorRequired = [OperationStatus.APPROVE,/*...*/].includes(operation);
}
...
```

The problem arises when I change the operation value after submitting the form, which in turn modifies the `isEvaluatorRequired` value. This triggers the following error:

```
ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.
Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'. Expression location: EvaluationsComponent.component.
```

Which indicates that the problem is with `isEvaluatorRequired`, here: `[required]="isEvaluatorRequired"`.

I simplified the example to share only the elements around the issue. I want to know why is it giving the error altough it changes the behavior correctly?

---

### Update Dec 9, 2023

I thought the problem was with the binding in `[required]`, but, actually the problem was here:

```
[ngClass]="{'is-invalid': form.submitted && formEvaluator.invalid}"
```

And it had the wrong behavior as well. Why is is not working?

---

### Update Dec 11, 2023

I solved it by replacing `formEvaluator.invalid` with `isEvaluatorRequired && !evaluatorId` which is manual validation of the field and it worked. But I still want to know why the `formEvaluator.invalid` reference cannot be used after the validation changes.

Comment: It seems like my issue is too similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69871087/18456344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that `isEvaluatorRequired` is changed after change detection runs. One way to avoid this is to use a Signal or Subject and the AsyncPipe:

```
[required]="isEvaluatorRequired$ | async"
```

Or you could force change detection after updating `isEvaluatorRequired`:

```ts
// ChangeDetectorRef needs to be injected:
private cdr = inject(ChangeDetectorRef);

// After changing isEvaluatorRequired:
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. Since I no longer had any errors, I don't use either of them, although the first option with the signal was the best in my case. I didn't like the second solution because I don't want to force change detection since I still don't know what thing in my code causes incorrect change detection.